# Does anyone know how to send a message to MSN Messenger?

Tags: .net, msn-messenger, msnpsharp

I'm trying to have my windows application send a message to two msn messenger accounts. So, I grabbed the code from the [MSNPSharp library](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/) and had a look in that.

I can authenticate/sign in without a problem. But once i've done that, I have no idea how to send a simple text message to two other users.

Do those users need to be *approved* ?

Can someone help me please - maybe show some sample code?

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [example code from the conversation form](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/source/browse/branches/MSNPSHARP_30_STABLE/Example/ConversationForm.cs) may help:

There is a Conversation object that you use to send the message. As soon as I get some more time I'll whip up an example.

Comment: Yeah. This is the hard bit. A conversation requires a contact. I don't know how to make a contact :( If my msn account username is : SomeName@SomeDomain.com ... then how do i add that contact, to send the message? I've figured the rest out a few days ago .. ...